# Hide password protected dynamic content in templates via shortcode

Tags: shortcode, password

I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-protector/

Enter the correct password to view the content↓

```
[passster password="123456"]content here[/passster]
```

adding to php↓

```
<?php 

 echo do_shortcode('[passster password="123456"]content here[/passster]');

?>
```

He can work

But I need to hide the content that contains PHP↓

```
<!--<hide content>-->
    <ul class="TPlayerNv">
                            <?php echo $optplayer; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="TPlayerCn BgA">
                            <div class="EcBgA" style="background-color:#EEEEEE!important;"> 
                                <div class="TPlayer">
                                    <?php echo $player; ?>
                                    <span class="AAIco-lightbulb_outline lgtbx-lnk"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="lgtbx"></span>
    <!--</hide content>-->
```

I am a newbie, he looks like this↓

```
<?php 

echo do_shortcode('[passster password="123456"]

<!--<hide content>-->
    <ul class="TPlayerNv">
                            <?php echo $optplayer; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="TPlayerCn BgA">
                            <div class="EcBgA" style="background-color:#EEEEEE!important;"> 
                                <div class="TPlayer">
                                    <?php echo $player; ?>
                                    <span class="AAIco-lightbulb_outline lgtbx-lnk"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="lgtbx"></span>
    <!--</hide content>-->


[/passster]');

?>
```

I know that this doesn't work

help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you actually used the `html` inside `php` like you have in the bottom of the question, but do try as below.

```
<?php 
if( echo do_shortcode('[passster password="123456"]'); ):
?> 
<!--<hide content>-->
    <ul class="TPlayerNv">
                            <?php echo $optplayer; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="TPlayerCn BgA">
                            <div class="EcBgA" style="background-color:#EEEEEE!important;"> 
                                <div class="TPlayer">
                                    <?php echo $player; ?>
                                    <span class="AAIco-lightbulb_outline lgtbx-lnk"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="lgtbx"></span>
    <!--</hide content>-->

<?php  echo do_shortcode('[/passster]')  endif; ?>
```

Update: Since I couldn't find anything related to this on your plugin's documentation, give following methods a try if above is not working

```
<?php if( echo do_shortcode('[passster password="123456"]') ): ?>

content here

<?php echo do_shortcode('[/passster]'); endif; ?>
```

or

```
<?php
$scode = '[passster password="123456"]';
if ( shortcode_exists( $scode ) ): ?>

content here

<?php echo do_shortcode('[/passster]'); endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried the above method
1 and 2 
（pages cannot be displayed）
3 
（The page is normal but I can't see the password. He didn't work）

Comment: @1400309 Did you asked from the plugin developer if there's any way for you to have conditional action with the shortcode? They'll have a better answer than me for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
<?php if ( true === passster\PS_Conditional::is_password_valid( 'passwordHere' ) ) { ?>
  <div>
    <?php echo the_content();?>
  </div>
```

etc...

```
<?php } ?>
```

Found and implemented from here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/do_shortcode-command-and-wrapping-content/